# ssis convert ddmonyyyy dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: ssis, ssis-expressions

Hi guys trying to convert

16JAN2014 --> 16/01/2014.  Any ideas??? i'm trying to avoid the horrendous expression of ? JAN : 1 ? FEB : 2 etc. etc.

SSMS will quite happily do SELECT MONTH('16JAN2014') to get me the number of month however MONTH( "16JAN2014" ) will not work in SSIS.

hmmm... tried code but keep getting error below...

[image]

Comment: How about using `-- today’s date in the format DD/MM/YYYY -->

RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DAY(GETDATE()),2) + "/" + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)MONTH(DATEADD("d",31,GETDATE())),2) + "/" + (DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(GETDATE())` in an expression.

Comment: hi the date is a column in the dataflow (string) i need to reference that

Comment: How many rows do you expect to need to do this conversion upon?

Comment: The files i'm importing aren't MASSIVE but would like to do this on up to around 1000 rows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a Script Component to perform the conversion!  Be sure to set your read / write variables of course!  It's quite easy for use specific locale settings with the .NET framework, so a Script Component should be superior than trusting the database to correctly do the conversions for you.

**Using a Script Component to Parse a DateTime Value from a String**

```
    using System.Globalization;

    ...

    public void Main()
    {
        String str = ( String )Dts.Variables[ "StringVariable" ].Value;

             // Good candidate for another variable, this is just an example.
        String format = "ddMMMyyyy"; 
        CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

        DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse( str, format, provider );
        Dts.Variables[ "DateTimeVariable" ].Value = dt;

        Dts.TaskResult = ( int )ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

**And in VB, if that's How You Roll™**

```
    Imports System.Globalization

    ...

    Public Sub Main()
            Dim str As String = Dts.Variables("StringVariable").Value
            Dim format As String = "ddMMMyyyy"
            Dim provider As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
            Dim dt As DateTime = Date.ParseExact(str, format, provider)
            Dts.Variables("DateTimeVariable").Value = dt
            Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
    End Sub
```

Comment: Hi i'm stuck with SSIS 2005 for this can you post in VB? Thanks...

Comment: There you go!  I haven't written a line of VB for about 4 years, so that was pretty interesting.  Based on how you've described the problem, you'll probably want to use the Script Component as a transformation in a Data Task Flow and configure an output column containing the derived date.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work but will mark as answer as it should work.  Anyone reading with this I ended up using an expression that checks initially if field is blank.  TRIM(@[Variable]) == "" ? NULL(DT_WSTR,1) : (DT_WSTR,20)((DT_DATE)(TRIM(SUBSTRING(@[Variable],1,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(@[Variable],3,3) + "-" + RIGHT(@[Variable],4))))